# SwiftUI ScrollView within NavigationLink and navigation

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I have a following swiftUI view:

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: Somewhere()) {
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Image("image")
                        Text("text")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        LazyHGrid(rows: [GridItem(.fixed(2))], spacing: 7) {
                            ForEach(someArray) { something in
                               SomeRectangleView()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It has an image and text at the top and a ScrollList below with small rectangles. It looks fine however I can only navigate to Somewhere() when tapping on the upper portion  of the view (the view above is an item in a list). Tapping on the portion that I assume is taken up by the scroll view does not make me navigate to Somewhere(), is there anything I can do to change that behaviour and make it so if i tap and not scroll on the ScrollView it will redirect me to Somewhere()?

Here's a screenshoot of how it looks:
[image]

If i click anywhere else than the area with the triangles (which is the scrollview) I get taken to Somewhere(), if i click there then nothing happens.

Comment: There is absolutely no understanding of what is going on and what you want. You need to add screenshots of the simulator so that we understand

Comment: @KaayZenn I just want to be taken to navigation's link destination when i click on the ScrollView

Comment: I tested your code by replacing the values with my own and it works. That's why I'm asking you to put some screenshots because I don't see the problem

Comment: @KaayZenn I've added the screenshoot now